# migrating oAuth from controller to middleware slim

Tags: php, slim, middleware, slim-3

i am using [This](https://github.com/pabloroca/slim3-simple-rest-skeleton) library to implement a API with Oauth, i want to ad da middleware to some of the routes, but i want the ouath to run before this other middleware so correct me if i am wrong but the way to do this is by making the oAuth a middleware instead of part of the controller.

The actual setup is like this.

the dependencies file is like this

```
$container['oAuth'] = function ($c) {

    $storage = new App\DataAccess\_oAuth2_CustomStorage($c->get('pdo'));

    // Pass a storage object or array of storage objects to the OAuth2 server class
    $server = new OAuth2\Server($storage);

    // add grant types
    $server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\UserCredentials($storage));
    $server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials($storage));
    $server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\RefreshToken($storage));

    return $server;
};
$container['App\Controllers\_Controller_oAuth2'] = function ($c) {
    return new _Controller_oAuth2($c->get('logger'), $c->get('App\DataAccess\_DataAccess'), $c->get('oAuth'));
};
```

And the actual controller is like this:

```
public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, _DataAccess $dataaccess, $server)
    {
        parent::__construct($logger,$dataaccess);
        $this->oAuth2server = $server;
    }

     /**
     * @param \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request
     * @param \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface      $response
     * @param array                                    $next
     *
     * @return \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface
     */
    public function validateToken($request)
    {
        $this->logger->info(substr(strrchr(rtrim(__CLASS__, '\\'), '\\'), 1).': '.__FUNCTION__);

        // convert a request from PSR7 to hhtpFoundation
        $httpFoundationFactory = new HttpFoundationFactory();
        $symfonyRequest = $httpFoundationFactory->createRequest($request);
        $bridgeRequest = BridgeRequest::createFromRequest($symfonyRequest);
        $token = $this->oAuth2server->getAccessTokenData($bridgeRequest);

        if (!$this->oAuth2server->verifyResourceRequest($bridgeRequest)) {
            $this->oAuth2server->getResponse()->send();
            die;
         }

        // store the user_id
        $token = $this->oAuth2server->getAccessTokenData($bridgeRequest);
        $this->user = $token['user_id'];

        return TRUE;
    }

    // needs an oAuth2 Client credentials grant
    // with Resource owner credentials grant alseo works
    public function getAll(Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
        if ($this->validateToken($request)) {
            parent::getAll($request, $response, $args);

        }           
    }
```

Now, what i tried is to make my function on my middleware file to add it to the routes needed, and it looks like this:

```
$oathMiddleWare = function ($request,$response,$next){

    $container = $this->$app->getContainer();
    $responsen = $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    $this->oAuth2server = $container->get('oAuth');

    $httpFoundationFactory = new HttpFoundationFactory();
        $symfonyRequest = $httpFoundationFactory->createRequest($request);
        $bridgeRequest = BridgeRequest::createFromRequest($symfonyRequest);
        $token = $this->oAuth2server->getAccessTokenData($bridgeRequest);

        if (!$this->oAuth2server->verifyResourceRequest($bridgeRequest)) {
            $this->oAuth2server->getResponse()->send();
            $responsen = $responsen ->withStatus(400);
            return $responsen;
         }

        // store the user_id
        $token = $this->oAuth2server->getAccessTokenData($bridgeRequest);
        $this->user = $token['user_id'];
        $next($request,$responsen);
        return $responsen;

};
```

i first tried `$container = $app->getContainer();` but it gave me an error saying `Call to a member function getContainer() on null`

and now with the code i just shared i get an error `Type: Slim\Exception\ContainerValueNotFoundException
Message: Identifier “” is not defined.`

Any suggestions into making this work?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue? I believe you should reference container in the middleware as `$this->getContainer()`.

Answer (score 0):

To access to your container inside middleware you can do as follow :

1/ create your middleware in specific file and class

```
<?php
namespace api\middlewares;

class SecurityMiddleware
{
    public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
    {
        // do your thing
        $response = $next($request, $response);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

2/ use the constructor of this class to set the container and access it in your middleware

```
private $container;

public function __construct($container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

3/ Add the middleware like this

```
// security check
$app->add(new \api\middlewares\SecurityMiddleware($app->getContainer()));
```

I made a Slim 3 API skeleton based on another api skeleton where I'm using this technique & oAuth2 authentication and where I define routes security inside each controller. You can go see if it can help you : https://github.com/mickaeleuranie/slim-api (I'm gonna add JWT and calls ratio when I'll have the time)

What I did was to define access of each controller inside them by defining an array inspired by Yii Framework like this :

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return [
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'actions' => [
                'edit',
            ],
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'actions' => [
                'get',
            ],
            'roles' => ['@'],
            'scopes' => 'admin',
        ],
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'actions' => [
                'login',
                'sociallogin',
                'signup',
                'contact',
            ],
            'roles' => ['?'],
        ],
    ];
}
```

This way I can access controller's rules from my middleware and check if user can access this route or not, according to if it's logged or not and if he has one of the authorized roles.